# SQL2008 merge replication fails to update depdendent items when table is added

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, merge-replication

**Setup:** an existing SQL2008 merge replication scenario.  A large server database, including views and stored procs, being replicated to client machines.

**What I'm doing:**

- adding a new table to the database
- mark the new table for replication (using `SP_AddMergeArticle`)
- alter a view (which is already part of the replicated content) is updated to include fields from this new table (which is joined to the tables in the existing view).  A stored procedure is similarly updated.

**The problem:** the table gets replicated to client machines, but the view is not updated.  The stored procedure is also not updated.

**Non-useful workaround:** if I run the snapshot agent after calling `SP_AddMergeArticle` and *before updating the view/SP*, both the view and the stored procedure changes correctly replicate to the client.

**The bigger problem:** I'm running a list of database scripts in a transaction, as part of a larger process.  The snapshot agent can't be run during a transaction, and if I interrupt the transaction (e.g. by running the scripts in multiple transactions), I lose the ability to roll back the changes should something fail.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  It seems like I must be missing something obvious, because I don't see why the changes to the view/sproc wouldn't be replicating *anyway*, regardless of what's going on with the new table.

Comment: has view and sp replication worked for you before with the current setup? I.e. other views that have been changed and successfully replicated?

Comment: The replication has been working for ages, but I'm not sure we've done this kind of change before.

Answer (score 1):

Are you making schema changes using ALTER VIEW | ALTER PROCEDURE? The article "Making Schema Changes on Publication databases" implies this is necessary, and that using Management Studio is not possible.

The article discusses schema changes in detail, in particular a section on Merge Replication and schema changes with regards to compatibility levels.

- [Making Schema Changes on Publication databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151870.aspx)

Comment: Yes, all of the changes are handled by scripts rather than management studio.  I'll have a look at the article though - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just Quick Hints as I leave:

Check ***Troubleshooting (Replication)*** in the Books Online help...

verify your security on each system

use some of the tools to help see what is happening

turn on the Profiler Trace on each box